# Get connectionstring from Azure KeyVault for use with ADF IS

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am rebuilding a SSIS package.
It wil run on ADF Integration Services.
It will loop through a number of databases outside of our own subscription.
The package gets the connectionstrings from  a SQL Azure database table. It just looks it up in a table based on a code

```
| CODE | CONNECTIONSTRING |

| SERVER1  | <connectionstring including credentials> |
| SERVER2  | <connectionstring including credentials> |
```

I would like this package to get the connectionstring **not** from a table (clear text, yuck!) but from an azure keyvault.

is this posible? If so, how? Otherwise, I know how to store the passwords using a hash but how do I unhash them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SSIS package you can retrieve a Ssecret from Key Vault using the REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret

Example request from doc:
GET https://myvault.vault.azure.net//secrets/mysecretname/4387e9f3d6e14c459867679a90fd0f79?api-version=7.1

How this call is made is up to you to decide. As an example you could make the call in a script task.